# Equivalent of Postgres' Window Alias in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, window-functions

In PostgreSQL, if I have multiple columns created using Window Functions. I can use the window clause to write the window definition. Eg

```
SELECT first_value(Price) OVER w,
  first_value(Volume) OVER w
FROM Stocks.TradeData
WINDOW w AS ( PARTITION by THour );
```

Is there an equivalent of this in SQL Server?

Comment: No.............

Comment: No reason Dale. 15/16 questions didn't have the relevant answer to my question in my Opinion, despite their upvotes. I will accept the 1 question's answer, which helped me to do so.

Comment: On top of this, Stack Exchange where this question might be said is more relevant, is highly convoluted and boxy into thin categories, categories which a general everyday programmer might not be aware of. At the end defeating the purpose of asking questions here.

Comment: I guess the downvotes came from the fact that the answer to this question is easily looked up in the manual. No need to search the internet or stackoverflow. The only  authoritative source for syntax  questions is the manual.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, **WINDOW** clause is supported by SQL Server 2022.

[SELECT - WINDOW - (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-window-transact-sql)

> Named window definition in the WINDOW clause determines the partitioning and ordering of a rowset before the window function which uses the window in OVER clause is applied

The query in question will work;

```
SELECT first_value(Price) OVER w,
       first_value(Volume) OVER w
FROM Stocks.TradeData
WINDOW w AS ( PARTITION by THour  ORDER BY <col_name>);
```

Answer (score 0):

As of SQL Server 2019, this is not supported

As [the manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) does not document such a clause, it's not available